# Detached window navigation in IdeaVIM

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, multiple-monitors, ideavim

In a two-monitor setup, it is convenient to detach an editor tab and place it on a secondary monitor.

Using IdeaVIM, I can navigate between the editor splits using vi-standard `ctrl+w w` shortcut.

Why the same shortcut doesn't allow me to cycle between the main editor window and the detached editor window? How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, IntelliJ IDEA platform doesn't provide an action to switch between windows. If there was such action, it could be mapped to the key sequence.

I think it's possible to leave a feature request on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.